# objective c No visible @interface for 'NSArray<NSString *>' declares the selector 'insertObject:atIndex:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

i want add object `date` in array `self.datesWithEvent`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<NSString *> *datesWithEvent;

[self.datesWithEvent addObject:date];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add / remove elements only to / from mutable objects

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<NSString *> *datesWithEvent;
```

However it's not sufficient to declare the property mutable, you have to initialize it with

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Or if you assign another (immutable) array to that property you have to call `mutableCopy`

```
datesWithEvent = [someArray mutableCopy];
```

Comment: -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 1):

Only mutable object/instance of class allows to modify its internal information/elements.

Please read [Object Mutability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html) & [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray), documents provided by Apple. It will help you to understand why mutable class object is required here.

You should/must use `NSMutableArray` array to add/insert object into array.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<NSString *> *datesWithEvent;
```

> **[NSMutableArray - addObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1411274-addobject?language=objc)** 
>   
> Inserts a given object at the end of the array.

Declaration

```
- (void)addObject:(ObjectType)anObject;
```

**Solution to your query:** 

Note: Your array is `NSString` type of elements, so your `date` object must be `NSString`.

(Try this and let me know, what problem do you face. Also share your fullcode, with information about `date` object. )

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<NSString *> *datesWithEvent;

datesWithEvent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *date = @"11-Dec-17";
[self.datesWithEvent addObject:date];
```

Comment: -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @ZouhairMouhsine - look at here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1411274-addobject?language=objc